# React component not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying out the examples in a book called *Fullstack React*. I don't know why the `Product` component isn't showing. I'm also a newbie to *React* and *StackOverflow*. Sorry for the mistakes I might make.

```
class Product extends React.component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='item'>
        <div className='image'>
          <img src='images/products/image-aqua.png' />
        </div>
        <div className='middle aligned content'>
        <div className='description'>
          <a> Fort Knight </a>
          <p> Authentic renaissance actors, delivered in  just two weeks.</p>
        </div>
        <div className='extra'>
          <span> Submitted by:</span>
          <img 
            className='ui avatar image'
            src='images/avatars/daniel.png'
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      );
  }
}

class ProductList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='ui unstackable items'>
        <Product />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And it also uses the semantic framework.

Comment: Please add your root `index.js` file and your `App.js` file. Also, anytime you use an ES2015 class component you do need to change `React.component` to `React.Component` and please explain the `className` convention you are using, I see white spaces, do they not need hyphens between them? I would need more info to help you out.

Comment: Just defining two classes won't make React render them. You need `ReactDOM.render` somewhere. So either that's the problem or you are not showing your full code, in which case it is more difficult to help you. Please either verify that this is the complete code or provide the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

`React.component` should be `React.Component`

You can also import Component at the same time as main React, e.g.

`import React, { Component } from 'react'`

Comment: Thanks for the 'React.Component' correction but it still didn't work